# グーグルアナリティクスで自分自身を除外したい

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics-api

前提・実現したいこと

swiftで日記アプリを作っています。

アプリはすでにリリースしており、グーグルアナリティクスでデータ収集しています。 
しかし、そのデータに自分が開発をするためにアプリを起動、操作した分も含まれてしまいます。

調べてみたところ、自分自身のデータを除外するためにはIPアドレスで判定するという方法が出てきたのですが、スマートフォンなのでIPアドレスが変わってしまうので難しいと判断しました。

アプリにグーグルアナリティクスを組み込んでいる場合、どのようにすれば自分自身のデータを除外できるのでしょうか。

また、タイミングや極端なスクリーン数から明らかに自分自身の操作によるデータなのにもかかわらず、地域がyokohamaであったり、minatoであったりと、正確なデータが反映されていません。 
どういった原因が考えられ、どのように対処すれば正確なデータが得られるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

補足
他のサイトでも質問させていただきましたが、解決に至っていない状況のため質問させていただきます。
https://teratail.com/questions/31595

Comment: 補足のサイトでBAを選ばれ解決されたようですが、こちらでも解決した内容を自身で記載し承認したほうがいいと思います。・・・それとも解決されていないのですか？

Comment: 申し訳ありませんでした。
以後気をつけます。
時間を空けないと自己回答を承認できないようなので、時間を空けて承認します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

他サイトで教えていただき解決しましたので、解決法を書かせていただきます。

google analyticsにはデバッグビルドを計測データに反映しないように、dryRunフラグというものが用意されています。

このように記述することで計測データに反映しないようにできます。

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] setDryRun:YES];
```